# Emacs $PATH in shell VS emacs (getenv "PATH")

Tags: shell, emacs, path, environment-variables

After launching emacs from the terminal, if I eval

`(getenv "PATH")`

I find that the list is the same as `type -p $path` on the terminal. 
so far so good.

But if I `M-! type -p $path` which according to the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell.html) executes the command, the output list is different.

Notably, it starts with

```
/usr/local/bin 
/usr/bin 
/bin 
/usr/sbin
/sbin 
/opt/X11/bin 
/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin 
/usr/texbin 
..
```

Could anyone point me to a documentation which explains this behavior ?

Comment: Could there be a difference between `path` and `PATH`? What happens when you run ``M-! echo $path`` vs ``M-! echo $PATH``?

Comment: nope, no difference... I removed the ambiguous programs from all those 'system directories' but that's a quite annoying non-determinism. some background command were picking up the 'wrong' version of a program.

Answer (score -1):

Wrt the doc part of your question, see:

- The Elisp manual, node [System Environment](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/System-Environment.html)
- The Emacs manual, node [Environment Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Environment.html).

And see `C-h f getenv`.

Comment: Just guessing but... "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. To determine if you deserve an upvote a reader would have to read 3 separate sources and guess which part you meant. I personally prefer answers that are still relevant even if the contents of an external source are updated/disappear.

Comment: @Gerry: Good point. But in this case the question was *"Could anyone point me to a documentation which explains this behavior?"* It wasn't *"What's the explanation for this behavior?"*

Comment: Yes I read that. I still think answers are best when they stand on their own despite how the question is asked. You can answer the question while also providing why you think that is the correct answer (i.e. quoting the important part)